# How is Setup class instantiated in MVVMCross in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvm, mvvmcross

I'm starting learning MVVM cross, In the android app, I have a splash screen class:

```
 [Activity(MainLauncher = true,
        Label = "@string/app_name",
        Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash",
        NoHistory = true,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class SplashScreen : MvxSplashScreenActivity
    {
        public SplashScreen() : base(Resource.Layout.SplashScreen)
        {

        }
    }
```

and this is the Setup class:

```
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
    {
        protected Setup(Context applicationContext) : base(applicationContext)
        {
        }

        protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

the problem is that the debugger doesn't hit the constructor of the Setup Class, instead I get "An unhandled exception" after the constructor of the splash screen

[image]

**EDIT**

I've already defined the App class in the PCL project:

```
public class App : MvxApplication
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();

    }
```

also defined the AppStart:

```
 public class AppStart : MvxNavigatingObject, IMvxAppStart
        {
            public async void Start(object hint = null)
            {
                //hardcoded login for this demo
                //var userService = Mvx.Resolve<IUserDataService>();
                //await userService.Login("gillcleeren", "123456");

                ShowViewModel<MainViewModel>();
            }
        }
```

The main reason behind this project is to understand the sequence of code required and executed by MVVM Cross, so I provide the minimum code till it runs successfully without runtime errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

I have read your code again more thoroughly and I can see the issue now. You defined the constructor of the `Setup` class as `protected`, which makes it invisible for activation.

On MvvmCross for Android the magic happens inside `MvxAndroidSetupSingleton` class (see the [source code here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/70f8e465a0259302276baaa81ee140853a450fcf/MvvmCross/Droid/Droid/Platform/MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.cs)) which searches for the `Setup` type you defined. The `FindSetupType` method looks for your defined `Setup` class first and then inside the `CreateSetup` method `Activator.CreateInstance` is used to build the `Setup` instance. The `CreateInstance` method variant used however searches only for `public` constructors, which means it doesn't find your protected one. The result is that it cannot build the `Setup` class and crashes.

### Original answer

The reason this happens is that you have no `Core` libary that would define the `MvvmCross` App class and would initialize other required setup. I suggest you to start with a [simple tutorial](http://jonathanroux.com/2016/05/05/your-first-project-with-xamarin-and-mvvmcross-4/) or to look into the [official sample projects](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples) to see what is necessary to make MvvmCross work in a Xamarin.Android app.